# Binding Gridview with where Clause does not work

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, userid

I have a gridview filled with product information.
SQL table looks like this:

ID||UserID||Name||Price||

and I want that the ID of the product matches with the id of the Users (User_ID). (I have a own SQL table with User Information).

I have this Code, but the gridview does not show something. Its just empty...

```html
protected void BindGrid()

        { string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConn"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                { //Land ergänzen
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From Product WHERE UserID=@UserID";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SessionHelper.User.ID);
                    using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        ad.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


aspx:

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="gridview" Width="100%" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#a8c066" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />     
    </Columns>
```

Comment: Can you please also share the aspx page code and the error message you faced?

Comment: What result do you get running the query in SQL Management Studio?  Also, SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(..) has been depreciated - you should use SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(..)

Comment: when you run that sql statement in sql, do you get any results back?

Comment: the page is just empty, no errors... but when I write "Select * From Product"  it works perfect, but unfortunately thats not what I Need. I changed it to AddWithValue, still does not work....

Comment: Delete cmd.Parameter line and try this. The number 1 is just example for test. and lets see if it can work.  It should be placed under SqlDataAdapter.    ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@yourparameter", SqlDbType.Int)); ad.SelectCommand.Parameters["@ yourparameter"].Value = 1;

Comment: and it's better to specify the structure of DataTable like, DataTable dt = new DataTable("Product");